# Flutter API Error "HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid"

Tags: android, flutter, api, http-error

```
void send() async
{
var bb=json.encode(listModel.toJson());
var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(
  "http://10.0.2.2:1066/api/Storedata/Add"),
  body: bb,
 headers: {"Content-type": "application/json"},);
if (response.statusCode == 201)
 {
   print("Done");
 }
else
  {
    print(response.body);
    print(response.statusCode);
  }
}
```

In "bb" variable all data show in json format when i debugged. but show this error "HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid". Please Help!!!!.
This json data is working in Postman.

!!!!Update!!!!
Postman screenshot
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BebaLfMS1G-GYPAcEQIHrXOg17aNaa7Y/view?usp=sharing

Comment: try localhost instead of this 10.0.2.2

Comment: i have tried "loclhost" , but did not work.

Comment: http://10.0.2.2:1066/api/Storedata/Add Can you share the web output of this address?

Comment: I did not tried in web. i need in android emulator.

Comment: I think you misunderstood, so when you paste this address into a browser bar, it should output an output.

Comment: this API work in Postman with localhost address

Comment: Update the question with a screenshot of the working Postman *request*